# CSS3 Button with an arrow on the right (center)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a button something like below image :

[image]

I can achieve this by using below css but I cannot do it using pure css. Between this is my first time using css.

I want to make it using css3 and bootstrap so it will be mobile friendly.

```
#main .btn-orange {
    background-color: #a14d0f;
    background-image: url("/media/img/btn-orange-icon.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 143px 2px;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 40px;
    margin-left: 64%;
    width: 11%;
    cursor: pointer; }
```

Anyone ?

Comment: Do you care that the button is orange? If not, you can use one of Bootstrap's many built-in button styles.

Comment: @sredmond yep. I need the button in orange

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the icon with an ASCII symbol if you want

```
content:" \27a4 ";
```

Comment: cool but how to add the black border between Book Now and icon ?